# Parsing generic functions in Java

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-programming

So I have this piece of code which uses several maps to store some simple classes.
Now I also want to look op some of the values based on for example the x position of this item. I tried to do something with Generics and lambda's, but it just didn't work out. Also if there is an easier way to do this, please tell. I have most of my experience in Python, so this might just not be practical in Java.

```
interface Compare {
     public <T, P> boolean apply(T obj, P comp);
}

class Utils {
    public static <T, P> List<T> retrieve(Collection<T> args, P value, Compare c) {

        List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T i: args) {
            if (c.apply(i, value)) {
                r.add(i);
            }
        }

        return r;

    }
}

class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
}
```

This doesn't raise any errors as of yet, but when I try to actually use the retrieve function on a HashMap it doesn't work.

`Point p = Utils.retrieve(points.values(), 0, (Point p, Integer x) -> {return p.x == x;});`

There are two errors in eclipse:

1. At Utils.retrieve, eclipse notes that: The method retrieve(Collection, P, Compare) in the type Utils is not applicable for the arguments (Collection, int, (Point p, Integer x) -> {})
2. At the lambda expression, eclipse notes that: Illegal lambda expression: Method apply of type Compare is

How would one handle this situation? My thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want `interface Compare<T, P> { boolean apply(T obj, P comp); }`, with the generics on the interface, not the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fairly close to getting the code you're after.

Firstly, move the generic parameter declaration to the interface (as the esteemed Esquire Wasserman suggests in his comment).

```
interface Compare<T, P> {
    public boolean apply(T obj, P comp);
}
```

Now you just need to modify the way you're calling your new toys. I've created a main method with the following code and it works nicely:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>(8);
    points.add(new Point(0, 0));
    points.add(new Point(1, -1));
    points.add(new Point(1, 1));
    points.add(new Point(-1, -1));
    points.add(new Point(-1, -1));
    System.out.println("Set<Point> points:\n" + points);

    Compare<Point, Integer> sameX = (p, x) -> p.x == x;
    List<Point> matchingPoints =
            Utils.<Point, Integer>retrieve(points, 0, sameX);
    System.out.println("\nmatchingPoints:\n" + matchingPoints);
}
```

I've used a simple `Set<Point>` here because I don't know what you're intending to store in a `Map`, but calling `Map.values()` will produce a `Collection<Point>` just as well as the `Set<Point>` does in this example.

The reason this works is that you specify the parameter types to the generic static method in the angle-brackets immediately before the name of the static method: `Utils.<Point, Integer>retrieve` and you don't put the types inside the lambda. It's also worth saying here that lambda expressions should be as compact as possible, so rather than `{return p.x == x;}` you can simply have `p.x == x`.

Note, however, that in order to see the output in a readable form, you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Point` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
}
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Set<Point> points:
[Point(-1, -1), Point(0, 0), Point(1, -1), Point(-1, -1), Point(1, 1)]

matchingPoints:
[Point(0, 0)]
```

(Also note that you don't have to move the lambda out of the call to the `retrieve` method, but it makes the code tidier, and fits better in this narrow Stack Overflow window.)

### Addendum

Your follow-up comment made me realise that your `Utils.retrieve` method was going to hit trouble unless exactly the right sort of `Compare` method was passed to it. Rather than leave things open to chance, it's better to lock this down by modifying the signature of your `retrieve` method so that it becomes this:

```
public static <T, P> List<T> retrieve(Collection<T> args,
        P value, Compare<T, P> c) {
```

Now the `Compare` object which is passed to `retrieve` *must* take the same types  which apply to the `Collection<T>` and the `value`. Once you've made this change you can inline your lambda expression like this:

```
List<Point> matchingPoints = Utils.<Point, Integer>retrieve(
        points, 0, (p, x) -> p.x == x);
```

You won't get errors now, because the strict type applied to the `Compare` parameter in your `retrieve` method allows the IDE (and compiler) to see that the lambda must be of type `<Point, Integer>`.

Comment: When I try to implement the lambda inline instead of out of the call to the `retrieve` method, it starts to give errors about it the p and the x being objects. Do you need the `<Point, Integer>` somewhere?

Comment: In trying to inline the lambda, I realised that the original `retrieve` method was being far too relaxed about the type of `Compare` object it accepted. I've created an addendum to my answer to explain how to constrain the `Compare` parameter, and this also makes it possible to inline the lambda without error.